# light queries that could help manage dependencies in the sp with dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dependencies

Is it natural that SQL Server does not catch objects dependencies in stored procedures through dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSp (@filter nvarchar(max)) AS
    exec ('select * from testTable where 1=1 AND '+ @filter)
```

Here SQL Server will not detect dependency between `testTable` and `testSp`.

What kind of "advice" do you have for the DBMS? I propose it could be very "cheap query" :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSp (@filter nvarchar(max)) AS
    -- cheap query like 'select top 1 @id=id from testTable' 
    exec ('select * from testTable where 1=1 AND '+ @filter)
```

So the question is which queries could be good candidates for that purpose?

P.S. Of course I expect that they all will have their minuses..

Answer (score 1):

When using dynamic SQL the query parts that are tekst (between quotes) are not detected as code by the IDE or the engine until the moment they are excuted. So this answers your first question, yes it is natural.

The only way around this that I can think of is to create a view using the generated output of the dynamic sql and check if the view definition is still valid at any point you want to check if the procedure is valid.

Usually when you need to do something like this there is an earlier departure from standard methods that if handled removes the need for such silly tricks.

Example:

```
USE demo
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM dbo.employees'
DECLARE @view NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
CREATE VIEW dbo.test_view 
AS ' + @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @view

BEGIN TRY 
DECLARE @validation int = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM demo..test_view)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'Dynamic SQL out of date'
END CATCH
```

Comment: Could you explain this: "to create a view using the generated output of the dynamic sql " . Can we use dynamic sql in views? P.S. It is not a "silly", dependency report is extremely important tool for legacy systems. I really ready to pay some price for it.

Comment: updated the post to show the code you could use for this. If you want to hire someone for it I think I can find the time ;)

Comment: could you provide your email in the SO profile so I could contact you about ";)"

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij I've put my linkedin link as a website, add me there

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOEXEC ON
    select * from testTable
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

do the job: code really not executed, but dependecy is declared.